# What is the Clojure equivalent of __FILE__ (found in Ruby & Perl)

Tags: clojure

In ruby I frequently use `File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))` for loading config files or files with test data. Right now I'm trying to load some html files for a test in my clojure app and I can't figure out how to do it without hard coding the full path to the file.

edit:
I'm using leinigen if that helps in any way

ref: __FILE__ is a *special literal* which returns the filename (including any path) given to the program when executed. see ([rubydoc](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000004) & [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
*file*
```

[API Reference](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/) (add `*file*` to the url)

Comment: how do you get the full path?

Answer (score 9):

Here is one way to replicate that in Clojure:

```
(defn dirname [path]
  (.getParent (java.io.File. path)))

(defn expand-path [path]
  (.getCanonicalPath (java.io.File. path)))
```

Then your Ruby line `File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))` in Clojure would be this:

```
(expand-path (dirname *file*))
```

See [Java interop docs](http://clojure.org/java_interop) for `.getParent` & `.getCanonicalPath`.

NB. I think `*file*` always returns the absolute (though not canonical) pathname/filename in Clojure.  Whereas __FILE__ returns the the pathname/filename provided at execution.  However I don't think these difference should effect what your trying to do?

/I3az/

Answer (score 8):

Neither of the 9 point solutions is correct. *file* gives you a file relative to the classpath. Using .getCanonicalPath or .getAbsolutePath on *file* will give you a nonexistant file. As pointed out in [this old thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/clojure/cg7tFlgZYSw), you need to use ClassLoader to resolve *file* correctly. Here's what I use to get the parent directory of the current file:

```
(-> (ClassLoader/getSystemResource *file*) clojure.java.io/file .getParent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on user83510's answer above, the full answer is:

```
(def path-to-this-file 
  (clojure.string/join "/" [(-> (ClassLoader/getSystemResource *file*) clojure.java.io/file .getParent) (last (clojure.string/split *file* #"/"))]))
```

It ain't pretty but it works :P